# JSON response TypeError - 'The "data" argument must be of type string'

Tags: php, json, authentication

The API I'm trying to fetch an access token gives me the following instructions *(you can check for yourself at https://developers.finove.com.br/authentication)*:

---

> Use your 'ClientId' and 'ClientSecret' to fetch an access token and the API authentication follows standard Oauth 2.0 protocols.

> The API only accepts requests in JSON, so all requests must include the header 'Content-Type: application/json'.

**The Parameters goes on thebody:**

*clientId* and *clientSecret* as a string

**The Response 200 will contain the acess Token as followed:**

{

accessToken: "eyJhbGciOiJSUz..."

}

---

Right, so I using the following function to POST a JSON request to the API, get the response and fetch the 'acessToken' value.

```
<?php
// ignore the $order because its not used in the function, just passed
private function finove_auth($order){ 
        
    $authurl = 'https://api.finove.com.br/api/auth/authenticate';
    $client_id = $this->apiId;
    $client_secret = $this->apiSecret; 

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $authurl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'Content-Type: application/json');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
            'clientId'      => $client_id,
            'clientSecret'  => $client_secret,
    ));

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

        if ( curl_errno( $ch ) ){
            // for printing on console and allowing me to check whats happening
            echo 'Error: ' . curl_error( $ch );
            return $this->finove_payment_processing( $order );
        }
        else {
            curl_close($ch);

            $auth_string = json_decode($data, true);
            print_r($auth_string); // to check the response on the console

            $this->finove_payment_processing( $order );
        }        
}
```

But something not working. On the console its returning me two things. Firts its

```
Fixed malformed JSON. Original:
```

and second is:

```
    array(7) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(9) "TypeError"
      ["message"]=>
      string(112) "The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined"
      ["errors"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["table"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["constraint"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["paramName"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["stack"]=>
      string(585) "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined
        at Hmac.update (internal/crypto/hash.js:84:11)
        at ApiKeyService.verify (/usr/src/app/dist/api/services/ApiKeyService.js:15:18)
        at AuthController.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/dist/api/controllers/AuthController.js:17:48)
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at fulfilled (/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:114:62)
        at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)"
    }
```

Can't figure it out what I'm doing wrong but it seens that the clientId and ClientSecret are not beeing send as they should.

Comment: The documentation for the endpoint you linked indicates that you should be passing these parameters as part of the POST request body, not as a URL parameter. Can you elaborate as to how you reached the conclusion that the way you've reflected this in your code currently *should* work counter to the documentation?

Comment: @esqew I've changed the method, but still not working :/

Comment: You have an extra , after the $client_secret

Comment: You mean the last argument of the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS array? It don't think it makes difference. I removed it just to be sure and the problem remains

Comment: Don't edit your question to say _"Solved"_. Please add the solution as an answer below

Comment: Okay, i fixed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works:

```
<?php
private function finove_auth(){
    
// Get the id and secret values
    $clientId = $this->finoveID; 
    $clientSecret =  $this->finoveSecret;       
    $url = "https://api.finove.com.br/api/auth/authenticate";

// encode to json
    $data = array("clientId" => "$clientId", "clientSecret" => "$clientSecret");                                                                    
    $data_string = json_encode($data);   

    // begin the request
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, [ // request properties
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "Content-Type: application/json"
        ],
    ]);
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl); // execute the request
    $err = curl_error($curl); // get error if occur
    
    curl_close($curl); // close the request
    
    if ($err) {
        print_r("cURL Error #:" . $err); // print error to log
    } else {
        print_r($response); // print value to log
    }
  
}
```

It seens that the problem was that I was not putting the infos inside a array and using Json_decode() properly. Using the Insomnia app: https://insomnia.rest to check the JSON response from the API really helped aswell.